# Error while publishing encoder ticks in Arduino

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, encoders, rosseral-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Arduino Uno to publish Rotary Encoder ticks. I have used the following code to publish the encoder values to ROS and ended up in the error

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int16.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int32.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int64.h>
#include <std_msgs/Float32.h>

int val;
 int encoder0PinA = 2;
 int encoder0PinB = 3;
 int encoder0PinZ = 4;
 int lwheel = 0;
 int encoder0PinALast = LOW;
 int n = LOW;

ros::NodeHandle  nh;

std_msgs::Int16 lwheelMsg;
ros::Publisher lwheelPub("lwheel", &lwheelMsg);   /

 void setup() {
   Serial.begin(57600);  
   pinMode (encoder0PinA,INPUT);
   pinMode (encoder0PinB,INPUT);
  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(lwheelPub);

 }

void loop() {
  
   n = digitalRead(encoder0PinA);
   if ((encoder0PinALast == LOW) && (n == HIGH)) {
     if (digitalRead(encoder0PinB) == LOW) {
       lwheel--;
     } else {
       lwheel++;
     }
     Serial.print (lwheel*0.97);
     Serial.print ("mm/");
lwheelPub.publish(&lwheelMsg);
   }
   encoder0PinALast = n;
nh.spinOnce();
 }
```

ERROR

```
[WARN] [WallTime: 1473618880.299270] Serial Port read returned short (expected 2 bytes, received 1 instead).
[WARN] [WallTime: 1473618880.300057] Serial Port read failure:
```

I found some fixes which told to change the baud rate, i tried them but didn't help. Someone please help me to fix the issue and direct me to correct ROS Arduino node to publish encoder ticks to ROS with interupt.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243531/error-while-publishing-encoder-ticks-in-arduino/) by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 173 on 2016-09-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-09-11**:
Don't use Serial.print() and rosserial: https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/issues/238 . Feel free to comment on that issue if this helps.

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2016-09-12**:
Thanks, that fixed the issue. But i am just getting "0" in ros topic. When i run the plain Arduino code to visualize the result in serial monitor i am getting perfect results. still there is a communication problem b/w Arduino & ROS

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-09-12**:
I don't see anywhere in your code where you actually put the lwheel encoder value into the message.

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2016-09-13**:
1wheel=lwheel. there some problem in pasting "L", My actual code is lwheel in all the places of 1wheel, i have edited now but still it looks like "1". It is the font style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You never assign a value to `lwheelMsg`, so it's always 0.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2016-09-13**:
Thank you, i have fixed it

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2020-02-24**:
Hi, I want to do same thing but unfortunately ı did not solve my problem yet. If you don't mind, would you please share the arduino and ros code with me?